# How to optimize update_all calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, update-all

Currently, I'm doing the `update_all` with concatenation like this:

```
collection.update_all(flag: false)
collection.update_all(["description = CONCAT(description, ?)", 'not_available'])
```

Is it possible to do it at once?

Obviously, this construction doesn't work:

```
collection.udpate_all(flag: false, ["description = CONCAT(description, ?)", 'not_available'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_all` can take array, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
collection.udpate_all([
  "description = CONCAT(description, ?)", flag = ?,
  'not_available',
  false
])
```

Comment: Two bind variables don't work for some reason. I came up with such solution
`collection.update_all(['desc = CONCAT(desc, ?), flag = FALSE', 'not_available'])`